# WordPress: Getting Error After Every Time I Publish My Post

Tags: wordpress

I dont know what is happening with my site its showing this error every time i publish any post !!!!

```
{"success":"false","error":{"message":"Wordpress Error - {}"}}
```

I tried:

- deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).
- switching to the default theme to rule out any theme-specific problems.
- re-uploading all files & folders - except the wp-content folder and wp-config.php & root .htaccess files - from a fresh download of WordPress. Make sure that you delete the old copies of files & folder before uploading the new ones.

Please help me out thank you :)

Comment: Is the error log saying anything? Perhaps when enabling error_reporting.

Comment: there are no any error log